# Using non-integer roots for synthetic division in polynom

Tags: polynom

I want to use the `polynom` package for synthetic division. However, while it works well for integer roots it does not take non-integer inputs.  For example this works well:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
    \polyhornerscheme[x=4]{2x^5-3x^4-23x^3-3x^2+51x+36}
\end{document}
```

But I don't know how to use a non-integer such as `\sqrt{3}` as a root:

```
\polyhornerscheme[x=\sqrt{3}]{2x^5-3x^4-23x^3-3x^2+51x+36}
```

Are there any workarounds to this problem, or am I just better off writting out the division manually in a table.

My apologies if this is a silly question, I'm new to both LaTeX and the `polynom` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Go to http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/polynom/polynom.pdf and in the documentation pg 3 it is clearly stated that it only works for integers.

Comment: OK, I had just hopped that there might be some other workaround or similar package.  How can I mark this question as resolved?

Comment: One of the entries in the line of small, grey words to the bottom left of your post should be 'close'.  I believe that'll do it.

Comment: @LSpice There is still some chance. For example, fixing an algebraic number ζ, one can calculate its minimal polynomial by hand. Then use `\polylongdiv` with customized layout.

Comment: @Symbol1, is your reply directed to me or to the poster?  I was just trying to advise "How can I mark this question as resolved?"

Comment: @LSpice mainly to OP. But since my comment follows yours, I would like to ask you if it *is* a chance. Oh, by the way, OP would see **delete** instead of **close**.

Comment: @Symbol1, for my questions, I see both 'close' and 'delete'.  Your suggestion is a neat idea, but, while the remainder returned by `\polylongdiv` in your suggestion will have the same value at the chosen number as the original polynomial, that still leaves the problem of finding what that value *is*.  I don't know if that's the OP's goal, so this may or may not answer the original question.